# Twitter API : Not Getting User Email - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-api

I'm getting **error** like

> **Unknown Property** – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>
> **Setting unknown property**: yii\authclient\clients\Twitter::requestEmail

Whenever I am including `'requestEmail' => 'true',` in `'authClientCollection' => [` for `components` in **web.php**

**web.php**

```
$config = [
  .
    .
  'components' => [
        .
        .
        'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
        'twitter' => [
          'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Twitter',
          'requestEmail' => 'true',
          'consumerKey' => 'IFK2OMG0rKIFK2Jt4rLvw',
          'consumerSecret' => 'ImTprQzaOMG0rKZsZiPDIvwIFK2aOMG0rKZsZiPD',
        ],
      ],
    ],
],
```

**UsersController.php** (Controller)

```
class UsersController extends CommonController 
{
    .
    .
    public function actions() {
    return [
      .
      .
      'auth' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
        'successCallback' => [$this, 'oAuthSuccess'],
      ],
    ];
  }

    .
    .
    public function oAuthSuccess($client) {
      // get user data from client
      $userAttributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
      var_dump($userAttributes); die;
      // do some thing with user data. for example with $userAttributes['email']
  }

}
```

**login.php** (View)

```
.
.
<p class="text-center">
    <?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
        'baseAuthUrl' => ['/users/users/auth']
   ]) ?>
</p>
.
.
```

But, as soon I'm omitting the line `'requestEmail' => 'true',` from **web.php**. It's working. I'm getting all required data except `email`. But, **problem is** : I am not getting `email` of user trying to login. Any idea, how can i get. Any hint/suggestion will be a great help for me. Thanks.

Comment: I think now it is possible to fetch user's email, please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33867823/386579

Comment: Yeah @shasikanth : I sent that request. Waiting for approval. Let's see what happens . *Thanks..*

Comment: Hi @shasikanth : I got mail from twitter stating "*Request Email Access Granted*". I followed the step what they have stated in mail. But, even though I am not able to access `email`. Do you have any idea regarding this. ?

Comment: Not sure why it is unable to fetch email. May be you are trying in your localhost. Also try with any public URL.

Comment: Can you try on same twitter profile or distinct? May be there can be profile without email (fo example registered by phone number).

Comment: Hi @jekaby : I got the solution. Even I posted it as answer. Now, I am getting *email* value. Thanks For Your Reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last, I got it.

This answer is for those who just installed *Twitter API* or *stuck in middle*.

Follow step by step.

**1)** If you have already created "*Consumer Key (API Key)*" & "*Consumer Secret (API Secret)*". 
        Then, directly go to **Point-5.**
     Else,
        Run this command `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-authclient "*"` in your system. And, generate "*Consumer Key (API Key)*" & "*Consumer Secret (API Secret)*". Follow [Create New App](https://apps.twitter.com/app/new) & [Twitter App Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation)

**2)** In **web.php**

```
$config = [
        .
          .
        'components' => [
              .
              .
              'authClientCollection' => [
              'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
              'clients' => [
                'twitter' => [
                  'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Twitter',
                  'consumerKey' => 'Generated Consumer Key (API Key)',
                  'consumerSecret' => 'Generated Consumer Secret (API Secret)',
                ],
             ],
          ],
    ],
```

**3)** In **YourController.php** (Controller) : Add `auth` section in function `actions()` And, function `oAuthSuccess($client)` (As I declared)

```
class UsersController extends CommonController 
    {
          .
          .
          public function actions() {
                return [
                  .
                  .
                  'auth' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
                    'successCallback' => [$this, 'oAuthSuccess'],
                  ],
                ];
            }

          .
          .
          public function oAuthSuccess($client) {
            // get user data from client
            $userAttributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
            var_dump($userAttributes); die;
            // do some thing with user data. for example with  $userAttributes['email']
          }
          .
          .

    }
```

**4)** In **YourView.php** (View)

```
<?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
    'baseAuthUrl' => ['/users/users/auth']
]) ?>
```

**5)**  Send a [Support Ticket](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform) to twitter for whitelisting your app. Select `I need access to special permissions` & Fill the required field & submit it.

**6)** After Few minutes/Hours, You will get an email stating/subject "*Request Email Access Granted.*". Email will say you to login at [apps.twitter.com](https://apps.twitter.com/).

After sucessfull login,

- click on your `Application Name`.
- Go to "*Settings*" tab, fill `Privacy Policy URL` & `Terms of Service URL` text fields. Save it through `Update Settings` button.
- Go to "*Permissions*" tab, Check `Request email addresses from users` checkbox. And, Save it  through `Update Settings` button.
- Go to "*Keys and Access Tokens*" tab, And Again "*Regenerate consumer key and secret*" in `Application Actions` section.
- After regenerating `Consumer Key (API Key)` & `Consumer Secret (API Secret)` save it to **Web.php** file.
- Don't forget to follow Last 2 Points in this section.

At The End,

**7)** Go To Sub directories:

`Root Folder -> vendor -> yiisoft -> yii2-authclient -> clients -> Twitter.php`

**Twitter.php**

Change

```
protected function initUserAttributes()
{
    return $this->api('account/verify_credentials.json', 'GET');
}
```

To

```
protected function initUserAttributes()
{
    return $this->api('account/verify_credentials.json', 'GET', ['include_email' => 'true']);
}
```

[**Note:** I am using Yii2-App-Basic. In Yii2-App-Advanced, Only File location path will get changed. ]

**Related Searched** :

- [yii2-framework-facebook-and-google-login-using-authclient-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550541/yii2-framework-facebook-and-google-login-using-authclient-not-working)
- [twitter-api-get-user-email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601146/twitter-api-get-user-email)