# How to get Email address of external login in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We are using Asp.Net Identity in MVC 5 to allow user log in with their social media accounts.

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

We use above API to retrieve information of accounts, but all of the accounts except Facebook have empty value for `loginInfo.Email`, how can we get the email address for this two social accounts:

- Microsoft Account
- Twitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe none of those providers propagate the user email as claims. You will have to query their APIs directly to obtain the email addresses.

To get the email addresses from a Microsoft Account, poke [the /me endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826526.aspx#info_rest)

Twitter does not allow you to retrieve a user email address. The advice here (as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601146/twitter-api-get-user-email) have ended up with too) is to ask the user for the email address from within your application.

Comment: The strangest thing is Facebook can return the email address by `loginInfo.Email` ...

Comment: @JerryBian - yes, identity providers *may* issue the email address as a claim. Google does this too. After all, both these providers use an email address as the primary user name. But they are not at all *required* to do this.